# map lookup error: cannot convert pair to enum value

Tags: c++, dictionary, c++11, lookup

I saw the following code suggested for creating a map lookup in another thread on stack overflow (I've modified it for my purposes but the general structure remains the same).

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
namespace kwd { //define namespace
    enum Options{ //enumerate alternatives
        Option_Invalid,
        assert
        //repeat for more options
    };
Options resolveOptions(string input){ //find enum values
        static const map < string, Options> optionStrings { //inputmap
            { "assert", assert }
            //repeat for more options
            };
//finally closing with
    auto itr = optionStrings.find(input);
    if( itr != optionStrings.end() ) {
        return *itr;
    }
    return Option_Invalid;
    }
}
string commentMake(string commentarray[]) {
        int commentarraylen =sizeof(commentarray)/sizeof(commentarray[0]);
        string comment = "";
        for(int i =0; i < commentarraylen; i++){
            switch (kwd::resolveOptions(commentarray[i])){
            case kwd::Option_Invalid:
            comment += commentarray[i] + " ";
            break;
            //repeat for more options
}}}
```

I need it or another method to look through a large number of different cases multiple times quickly so i want to avoid If-statements (since i understand they're quite slow). However when i run it i receive the following error:

```
spoofcode.cpp: In function ‘kwd::Options kwd::resolveOptions(std::string)’:
spoofcode.cpp:28:16: error: cannot convert ‘const std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, kwd::Options>’ to ‘kwd::Options’ in return
   28 |         return *itr;
      |                ^~~~
      |                |
      |                const std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, kwd::Options>
```

what would be a possible way to resolve this, or alternatively, is there another way to do it?

Comment: Take a quick look at the documentation:https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find. Find returns an iterator, i.e., both key and value as a pair. If you want the value, you have to use `itr->second;`.

Comment: `sizeof(commentarray)/sizeof(commentarray[0]);` will not work (`sizeof(commentarray)` returns the size of string pointer). Pass strings array by reference with deducing array's length or pass additional parameter to `commentMake` as length.

Comment: The error message is pretty good for this one. *cannot convert* So we know what went wrong *‘const std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, kwd::Options>’* the type we've got *to ‘kwd::Options’* the type we want. So somehow we need to turn what we get into what we want. Fortunately what we get contains what we want, we just need to know how to get what we need out of what we got. The rest is reading documentation.

Comment: @rafix07 yes i am aware, i'm going to resolve it, one error at a time!
Thank you very much midor